# What to do about warning: `extern` block uses type `u128`, which is not FFI-safe

Tags: c, rust, ffi, unsafe

I used the bindgen crate to create bindings from Rust to a C library but I get a whole bunch of warnings saying:

```
warning: `extern` block uses type `u128`, which is not FFI-safe
= note: 128-bit integers don't currently have a known stable ABI
```

What can I do about this warning? I assume I need to take some action to fix this, or can I ignore it?

Comment: see [rust-lang/rust#54341](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/54341) -- in short, you can't do this safely at the moment.

Comment: I have seen the issues but honestly I don't understand what this means. Does this mean it might work, have unexpected behavior or what exactly?

Comment: It means the behavior is undefined. It might work, it might cause a system exception, it might silently cause incorrect behavior. Additionally, any code that you write might work on one rustc version and not another, or might work differently between platforms. The reason it's not safe to use is because the compiler gives no guarantee that these types will cross the FFI boundary in a way that foreign code understands. In short: if you need to send 128 bits across FFI, do so using some other method for now (e.g. a pair of `u64`).